# Docker Container running.But page isnt working in localhost URL(Page didnt send any data)

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

I am newbie to Docker and Python.I have created a simple python application using Flask .I would like to run it in a Docker container.The docker container shows it is running.However when I access the url ,I get localhost didn’t send any data.

docker container ls shows my container running on localhost and port no 8081

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request



app = Flask(__name__)


 @app.route("/hello", methods=["GET","POST"])
 def hello():
     return "Hello World!"

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True, port=8081,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7

ADD app.py /

RUN pip install flask

EXPOSE 8081 

CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]

CMD ["python", "app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

When I run the same app.py in my local environment.I get the desired data on the localhost url. Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Image is tagged `dockerimage:latest` and I run it with:

```sh
docker run -it -p 8081:8081 dockerimage
```

And checking for the container with `docker container ls` shows:

```
0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp
```

Comment: How are you accessing this flask endpoint? And how are you running the container?

Comment: You need to forward the port when you run your container. e.g. `docker run -p 8081:8081 mycontainer`

Comment: Why do you have three run commands?

Comment: 1.Build Command: docker build -t dockerimage:latest . -f Dockerfile
2.Run Command:  docker run -it -p 8081:8081 dockerimage
3.Docker container ls returns  0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp

Comment: When you access that endpoint, what are you doing? And are you connecting to it through `http://localhost:8081/hello` ?

Comment: @C.Nivs Yes I am accessing it using http://localhost:8081/hello.I tried http://127.0.0.1:8081/hello as well as http://0.0.0.0:8081/hello.  But nothing works

Comment: Are you connecting via a browser? Do you see anything happening in the logs? Looks like you're running in non-daemon mode, so you should be able to see if Flask is receiving any traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems fine in your Dockerfile and the Flask script, but I will suggest two thing.

- Update base image to `python:3.7` as `2.7` will reach its end of life.
- Remove `CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]` this as there is only one `CMD` per dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine3.10 
RUN pip install flask
ADD app.py /
EXPOSE 8081 
CMD ["python", "app.py", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Now run the container

```
docker run -it --name my_app --rm -p 8081:8081 dockerimage
```

Open the browser and hit

http://localhost:8081/hello

or

```
docker exec -it my_app ash -c "apk add --no-cache curl && curl localhost:8081/hello"
```

One of the above should work.

If you the second command work then something wrong with host configuration.

Comment: Why have the user change their base image to an alpine version? If their example is vastly simplified (MCVE) and they rely on packages such as `numpy`, this will create new problems, such as requiring an update to gcc and fortran under the hood

Comment: I consider python is more suitable in case of a container which two or three time smaller then other image, but if that not able fulfil the requirment he can use `python:3.7`. as the scirpt is really simple and alpine suit well

Comment: For someone who is looking to optimize their container workflow, I'd agree. For a beginner, I'd stick with the vanilla images to minimize complication

Answer (score 0):

some different case happened with me, i was running the app inside Container, which was trying to access MySQL server (which was running on my local machine) outside the container then i need to add this line in my docker-compose file

```
extra_hosts:
  - "docker.for.mac.localhost:host-gateway"
```

and if you are using docker run command just use it like this

```
docker run -d \
  --name your-container-name \
  --extra_hosts="docker.for.mac.localhost:host-gateway" \
  your-image-name
```

above enables map `localhost` of your machine with container, so you can use any localhost post easily !

Thanks me later